Why use 'as' in TypeScript?
What’s the reason to use as if it is not changing the type? What am I missing?
In the first example I get 4 even though I said it is a string. On the second 22 even if I said number.
let num1: unknown = 2;
let sum: number = (num1 as string) + 2;
console.log("as string: ", sum); // 4

let num2: unknown = '2';
let sum: number = (num2 as number) + 2;
console.log("as number: ", sum); // 22

https://jsfiddle.net/yb549u3g/

TypeScript does not exist at runtime. A type assertion doesn't (can't) cast or convert anything.

let sum: number = (+num2 as number) + 2; // the unary + converts to number and 'as' allows us to manually set the data type of a variable

as = hack (for me)

as keyword exists only for typescript compile, more clarification

Typescript is a tool to statically analyze your code to prevent errors and make the code safer. I invite you to read Why does TypeScript exist?.
As I said, it statically analyzes your code. This means that TypeScript doesn't operate at runtime; in fact your TypeScript code will be built into JavaScript code (usually in a /dist folder) and your consumer will only use the JavaScript code.
Let's analyze the scenario you presented:
let num1: unknown = 2;
let sum = (num1 as string) + 2;
console.log("as string: ", sum);

Here, TypeScript doesn't throw any error because you can do string + number (JavaScript will automatically transform the number into a string and append it to your first one), so if you cast num1 as string, TypeScript will think that num will be something like "22" (note that TypeScript thinks now it's a string).
But if you look at the compiled code, you will find something like
let num1 = 2;
let sum = num1 + 2;
console.log("as string: ", sum);

And you can easily predict the console will print 4 (a number!).
This mismatch is due to your as casting operation, that is telling the compiler "don't worry about your prediction, I know that num1 is a string", which is a powerful tool. This is a perfect example to show you that you should use as only when you are really sure that your assertion is correct; otherwise you could trick TypeScript's compiler and it will undermine the type safety of your project, which is the whole purpose of using TypeScript in the first place.

Why would you use as?
When there is no way for the compiler to know what type you are using.
An example is when you are using built-in JavaScript Object.keyof
const myObj = {
  "foo": "foo",
  "bar": "bar"
}

const keys = Object.keys(myObj);

for (const key of keys) { // key has type string
  console.log(myObj[key])
  // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ foo: string; bar: string; }'.
  // No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ foo: string; bar: string; }'
}

const keysTyped = Object.keys(myObj) as (keyof typeof myObj)[]

for (const key of keysTyped) {
  console.log(myObj[key])
}

Here for example, since Object.keys returns string[], TypeScript has no way to know that keys is a valid way to access myObj property so it will throw an error. This error can be prevented by casting your Object.keys as as (keyof typeof myObj)[] so that the compiler knows that they are valid object keys.
Playground link

"as" is made to assert types at compile time, it has no effect at runtime.
Your example is like adding a Ferrari logo to your BMW, it won't go faster.

Typescript's sole purpose is at compile time and it doesn't exist at runtime.
as is a way of asserting to the compiler that you've checked something and are confident about its type. Using as is like saying:
"Trust me, I know what I'm doing. Treat num1 as if it were of type string."
