Why does mixing types work and not give an error?
I have created a string and passed it to a number-only function and it works. What I am doing wrong? I was expecting an error.
let number: string = 4;

function sum (num: number) {
  console.log(num)
}

sum(number)

https://codepen.io/tseitlin/pen/QWRLrzL?editors=0011

TypeScript DOES NOT EXIST at runtime - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78446551/why-use-as-in-typescript#comment138299710_78446551. The compiler will absolutely give you an error on that at transpilation time.

Typescript is valid only during compile time. At run time all the types are removed and only the JS code runs.
Looks like codepen does not show typescript errors. In fact it does not show any non run time errors.
Here is the same example in a TS enabled playground. It errors out
